# Adding a "New Button" option on Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please forgive me if this question is too vague or extensive.  I have limited experience with Access, SQL, and VBA and have a problem at work that I just can't solve.  I'm trying to add a "new button" button to the user interface on our Access database.

I would like it to maybe bring up another form that allows you to input a query you want to make into a quick link on the home page.  Obviously this would only be accessible to certain users but I can handle that part.

I don't necessarily need the code written, just an idea of where to start.  So far all I've been able to do is hard code a new query or link into a button each team I want to make one.  I want this process to be simplified so that anybody can make a button even if they don't know how to use Access very well.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated and feel free to tell me to get lost if this is too vast or general a question.

Comment: Please try to create index button (array button), you can load many button as required I think, make visibility of button array 0 to false, and give the new load button name to it's tag

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like it to maybe bring up another form that allows you to input a query
```

The above seems very confusing. You are asking how a form can be used or launched or displayed to allow the user to add a new record. Then you toss in this VERY unrelated concept of some query? What does some query have to do with adding a new record?

If you want to add a new record, and you are in a form that is displaying current records, then behind the button, you can execute this line of code to jump to a new record ready for data entry:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

So, that is one line of code.

If you want to launch an existing form and have it start out with a new clean fresh record, then use this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomers", , , , acFormAdd
```

The above will launch the given from in "add mode" and thus you are again on a new fresh record ready for data entry.

The issue(s) of some query etc. for the user What does that have to do with wanting the user to add a new record? So that part does not seem to apply to the basic idea of presenting a form with a new record which allows the user to add that record in question.

You have to explain what all the hub bub about this magic query issue but to jump a form to a new record for the user? Just use the first line of code behind a button.

And if you need to launch a form in "add mode", then use the 2nd example one line of code behind the button in question. None of this has really anything to do with some "query" in regards to you wanting the user to add a new record. You can expand on what you mean by some user query, but you have several options to jump an existing form to a new record, or launch a form in "add mode" to allow adding of a record. In these cases, you don't need nor want to write or deal with some SQL query.